# Remove a pattern in every row in a dataframe

Tags: r, gsub

I have a dataframe which every rows has a pattern that I want to remove.
My data frame looks like;

```
    Singer Name             Song Name
1   SEP>Karkkiautomaatti    SEP>Tanssi vaan
2   SEP>Hudson Mohawke      SEP>No One Could Ever
```

As it is shown above, every row has a pattern "SEP>" that I want to remove. I have tried using "gsub()" and "apply()" functions, but I could not succeed removing this pattern. I want this data frame like,

```
    Singer Name             Song Name
1   Karkkiautomaatti        Tanssi vaan
2   Hudson Mohawke          No One Could Ever
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option is to loop through the columns with `lapply`, usses `sub` to remove the substring "SEP>"

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) sub("SEP>", "", x, fixed = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `substr()`:

```
lapply(df, function(x) substr(x, 5, nchar(x)))

      Singer_Name         Song_Name
1 Karkkiautomaatti       Tanssi vaan
2   Hudson Mohawke No One Could Ever
```

In combination with `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
 mutate_all(list(~ substr(., 5, nchar(.))))
```